# How to merge queries in power bi with 2 primary keys

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

How do we merge two queries in power bi when the primary key is a combination of 2 columns.

for example i have 2 tables

Table A :

```
year
cost center
col a
col b
col c
```

Table B:

```
year
cost center
col x
col y
col z
```

The primary key in both the columns is a combination of the 1st two columns. How do i merge these two queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you merge the queries using the GUI, you can hold down `Ctrl` to select multiple columns from each table. (Make sure you select them in the same order on both tables.)

[image: Merge GUI]

Answer (score 1):

1. Either create a **new combined column** from year and cost center (in one table this key has to be unique) and use this new key for your relationship
2. Or **merge both tables** into a new table and than you can pick multiple columns to join on.

Answer (score -2):

For large tables (like ours we have 17 Million rows), we found that having created a combined column with composite keys improved the speed for merging, it still took about 1 hour, but an improvement from 90 minute without. I wonder if anyone else had the same experience, or if there are more we can do to increase the speed. Thanks!