# Power Query creating dupes upon Left Join

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I am trying to merge two tables to get 3 columns from the other table and it is creating 4 additional duplicate rows (in the actual report, which has led to more than 2 million rows). I have created a sample here and it even did the same thing to that. I was wondering if somebody could help me out here. I am doing a left outer join and have made sure that the tables do not have duplicates beforehand.

I am attaching screenshots of my sample file here:

[image] (Attendance)

[image] (Classes)

[image] (Merge Query with dupes)

Answer (score 2):

When you match on a column, it will pull over **all** rows corresponding to the value in that column. If that value isn't unique in the second table, it will create duplicates when you expand the merged table columns.

To me, it looks like you need to match on **three** columns since the classes table isn't unique in `School`, `ID`, or even `School` and `ID` combined (e.g. `101,234` show up more than once). So match up the `School` columns and `ID` columns and also match `Absent_Period` with `Bell_Period`.

Hold down `Ctrl` to select multiple column (in order) as in [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61499573).

Comment: Then the Classes table isn't unique even in those three columns.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you join tables on School and ID columns. Combination of these columns is not unique for both tables.

Comment: I cannot really join the School and ID columns since I am trying to find if the student was absent for the core classes which is the fourth columns in the classes table.

Comment: Look. You write, there are no duplicates in both tables. But you (obviously) tried to find duplicates in whole table, that doesn't make sense. Only uniqueness of your key columns (School and ID) is matter. And they are not unique. So, you have duplicates before merge. After merge they are multiplied. For example, for School = 101 and ID = 234 there are 2 rows n Attendance table, and 3 rows in Classes table. So after merge you have 2*3=6 rows.